# Selecting file using javascript then upload

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, html

I appended blob data (that I converted from urldata) to a form. The code I use is as follows:

```
var blob = dataURItoBlob(row.pict);
var fd = new FormData(document.forms[0]);
fd.append("uploadFile", blob);
```

I intend to set the blob as the selected file for an input with type file:

```
<input type="file" name="uploadFile" id="btn_pic" />
```

But when I click the submit button, server does not recognize the file I want to upload. The server reads the parameter as null (I am using ASP .NET MVC3). I use The code below in the server-side:

```
public ActionResult Create(Discussion d, HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile)
{
    ....
}
```

is there any way I can do to set the selected file using javascript?

Comment: Have you made the form multipart/form-data?

Comment: yes, but still server fetches nothing on the uploadFile parameter